# How to implement purification of the density matrix into a pure state of enlarged system in the quantum PCA algorithm?

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I am trying to implement the quantum PCA algorithm to reduce the number of features (over 700 features) for a machine learning model. The original algorithm is proposed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0401.pdf). I found [a tutorial](https://github.com/Haokai-Zhang/ExampleQPCA/blob/master/5qubit-qPCA.ipynb) from GitHub which I guess follows the method explained in the section 14.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03719.pdf). It' difficult to implement a mixed state as the density matrix. So, as mentioned in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.03719.pdf), we need to purify the density matrix into a pure state of enlarged system. This purification was implemented in the code cell [5] of the tutorial:

```
rho_eig_val, rho_eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(rho)
p_vec = np.concatenate((np.sqrt(rho_eig_val), np.sqrt(rho_eig_val)), axis=0)
U_vec = rho_eig_vec.reshape((4))
psi = p_vec * U_vec
print('The purified state is \n', psi)
rho_partial_trace = np.dot(psi.reshape((2,2)),psi.reshape((2,2)).transpose())
print('Verify the reduction to the original mixed state \n', rho_partial_trace)
```

I got a questions about this implementation:

The goal of quantum PCA is to obtain eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the density matrix representing the covariance matrix for features. But in this implementation, it calculates out eigenvalues and eigenvectors by using NumPy function `np.linalg.eig` which are then used for purification. If we already have these eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we don't need to continue to perform quantum PCA... Is there any other way to prepare the purified state without calculate these eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: it seems to me like these questions are rather different. The first is just asking how the purification procedure is formulated mathematically, while the second one is specific to the qPCA algorithm. I'd encourage splitting the question in two separate posts. Each post on the site should ideally only contain a single, laser-focused question. You can ask separate questions on separate posts.

Comment: @glS Thanks for your suggestion. I've split the question in two separate posts.